# How do I solve the error that I received when implementing the callback method?

Tags: wcf

I am currently developing a WCF duplex service and I am trying to implement the callback method in my client app however there is a error of

```
'App.CallbackHandler' does not implement interface member IPostingServiceCallback.retrieveNotification(Service.Posting)'
```

the service contract for my service are as follow

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode=SessionMode.Required , CallbackContract = typeof(IPostingServiceCallBack))]
public interface IPostingService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void postNotification(Posting post);
}

public interface IPostingServiceCallBack
{
    [OperationContract]
    String retrieveNotification(Posting post);
}
```

I have generated the proxy and added into the project file of my client and adding the endpoint address into the app.config.

**EDIT**

The code I have in my client app currently is

```
public class CallBackHandler : IPostingServiceCallback
{
    public void retrieveNotification()
    {
        //planning to do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client application needs to implement `IPostingServiceCallBack` and define the `retrieveNotification` method.

Say you have a client (not the proxy) that will be consuming your duplex service:

```
public class MyClient : IPostingServiceCallBack
{

    public String retrieveNotification(Posting post)
    {

       // Implement your logic here
    }
}
```

Note the above is a bare-bones example as a simple illustration.  Your client will probably derive from another class as well (depending on whether it's ASP.NET, WinForms, WPF, etc).

**Updated**

You're still not implementing the method.  Your callback interface is:

```
public interface IPostingServiceCallBack
{
    [OperationContract]
    String retrieveNotification(Posting post);
}
```

Your implementation is:

```
public class CallBackHandler : IPostingServiceCallback
{
    public void retrieveNotification()
    {
        //planning to do something
    }
}
```

You have `public void retrieveNotification()`, whereas the interface has `String retrieveNotification(Posting post)`.  The method signatures don't match.

You need to do:

```
public class CallBackHandler : IPostingServiceCallback
{
    public String retrieveNotification(Posting post)
    {
        // planning to do something
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, thats what I currently have in my client app. after typing this it will have the error as stated above.

Comment: @Thomas - I updated my answer based on the edit to your original question.